# To transfer a file from one windows machine(Local) to another windows machine(Server)

Tags: java, ftp, sftp, ftp-client

I want to write a code which will transfer a file from one machine to another in Linux and Windows platforms.

I used ssh libraries (sftp connections) to transfer file to Linux machine.

Now, I wanted to do same for Windows machine. Can someone please help me with this?

Description: To transfer a file from one windows machine(Local) to another windows machine(Server).

Also, I checked with FTP libraries in java, but I wasn't able to create a directory outside the folder created/shared for ftp.

Below is my code I am using currently for ftp.

```
      FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();  
      FileInputStream inputStream = null;  

      try {  
       // pass directory path on server to connect  
       ftpClient.connect("172.30.17.17");  

       // pass username and password, returned true if authentication is  
       // successful  
       boolean login = ftpClient.login("Administrator", "Password1!");  

       if (login) {  
        System.out.println("Connection established...");  
        inputStream = new FileInputStream("C:/Demo/abcd.txt");  

        boolean uploaded = ftpClient.storeFile("uploadedFile3.txt",inputStream);  
        if (uploaded) {  
         System.out.println("File uploaded successfully !");  
        } else {  
         System.out.println("Error in uploading file !");  
        }  

        ftpClient.makeDirectory("C:/Demo1"); //Unable to create this here

        System.out.println("Folder Created  successfully !");  


        // logout the user, returned true if logout successfully  
        boolean logout = ftpClient.logout();  
        if (logout) {  
         System.out.println("Connection close...");  
        }  
       } else {  
        System.out.println("Connection fail...");  
       }  

      } catch (SocketException e) {  
       e.printStackTrace();  
      } catch (IOException e) {  
       e.printStackTrace();  
      } finally {  
       try {  
        ftpClient.disconnect();  
       } catch (IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
       }  
      }  
     }
```

Comment: I would use ssh between windows machines as well. All you need is sshd installed.  Or you could share the folder you want to copy to/from.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Is it possible to use ssh between windows as well? Can you please give me an example or a source link to understand this more?

Comment: Here is an example using cygwin http://cygwin.wikia.com/wiki/Sshd and https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/install.121/e22624/preinstall_req_cygwin_ssh.htm#EMBSC150